# How not to reexplicit instance components properties in generic components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In react, I implement generic components like this :

```
export function CustomTextInput(props) {
    return (
        <TextInput
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
            style={{margin:20}}
        />
    )
}
```

And them I use them like this :

```
      <CustomTextInput
        placeholder="My placeholder"
        onChangeText={secretCode => setSecretCode(secretCode)}
      />
```

Is there a way not to have to re-explicit each property in the generic components ?
For example, by defining generic components like that :

```
export function CustomTextInput(props) {
    return (
        <TextInput
            props={props}
            style={{margin:20}}
        />
    )
}
```

... while still keeping the same implementation for component instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer props using the `spread syntax` as follows.

```js
export function CustomTextInput(props) {
    return (
        <TextInput
            {...props}
            style={{margin:20}}
        />
    )
}
```